# Convertir consulta de SqlServer a Linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

Buen día, tengo una tabla similar a esta:

```
create table TblDemo(
Id int primary key identity(1,1),
Fecha date,
Estado int
);

insert into TblDemo values
('2021-09-02',1),('2021-09-02',1),
('2021-09-16',1),('2021-09-23',1),
('2021-10-22',1),('2021-10-25',1),
('2021-11-28',1),('2021-12-01',1),
('2021-12-11',1),('2021-12-13',1),
('2021-12-15',1),('2021-12-22',1),
('2022-09-13',1),('2022-10-10',1),
('2022-10-14',1),('2022-10-20',1),
('2022-11-22',1),('2022-11-22',1),
('2022-11-28',1),('2022-11-29',1),
('2022-12-11',1),('2022-12-13',1),
('2022-12-15',1),('2022-12-22',1);
```

La consulta de sql obtiene la cantidad de registros mensuales del año especificado:

```
select COUNT(*) as Cantidad,MONTH(Fecha) as Mes
from TblDemo where YEAR(Fecha)=2021
group by MONTH(Fecha)
order by MONTH(Fecha) ASC
```

El resultado

[image: resultado]

Ahora quiero hacer lo mismo con Linq pero no comprendo como podría hacerlo tengo el siguiente método

```
public IEnumerable<DemoDTO> ObtenerConsulta(int año)
{
   var result = dbContext.TblDemo
                .Where(x=>x.Fecha.Year==año)
                .OrderBy(x => x.Fecha.Month)
                .GroupBy(x => x.Fecha.Month)
                .Select(y => new DemoDTO
                {
                   Mes = y.FirstOrDefault().Fecha.Month,
                   Cantidad = y.Count()
                }).ToList();
    return result;
 }
```

La clase

```
public class DemoDTO
{
   public int Mes { get; set; }
   public int Cantidad { get; set; }
}
```

La consulta en Linq me retorna 5 y 11

[image: res2]

Comment: Ya probaste la sugerencia de la exepción? Qué intentas lograr con `.First()`?

Comment: @Arriel pensé que podía acceder a la propiedad Fecha y obtener solo el mes, ahora con FirstOrDefault me retorna 5 y 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba esto:

```
public IEnumerable<DemoDTO> ObtenerConsulta(int año)
{
   var result = from x in dbContext.TblDemo
                where x.Fecha.Year == año
                group x by x.Fecha.Month into grupo
                orderby grupo.Key
                select new DemoDTO
                { 
                   Mes = grupo.Key,
                   Cantidad = grupo.Count()
                };
}
```

En esta consulta **Linq** primero se filtran los años que cumplan con la condición indicada y posteriormente se hace la agrupación correspondiente por el mes de la fecha, posteriormente se haría un ordenamiento ascendente por la clave que se empleó para agrupar los datos, que en este caso es el mes de la fecha y finalmente se construye el objeto indicado utilizando la **clase DemoDTO**, donde el mes de ese objeto será el valor de la llave por la que se agrupó y la cantidad será el total de los elementos que contiene dicha llave.

Comment: Me retorna lo mismo 5 y 11  (╥﹏╥)

Comment: Socio acabo de probar mi codigo y el tuyo y ambos funcionan perfectamente, revisa bien que estas haciendo, quiza hubo algo q te falto decir

Comment: Verdad ya lo solucioné no me di cuenta que tenía un error adicional :'v